# Json Deserialize a List with in a List

Tags: c#, json.net

Is it possible to deserialise a list with in a list using the JsonConvert.DeserializeObject?

```
Object: 
public class BusinessList
{
    public long Number{ get; set; }
    public string BusinessUnitCode { get; set; }
    public List<string> Codes { get; set; }
}

Json:

{"Number":111121,"BusinessUnitCode":"ABC","Codes":["11111-2","14333-8"]}

Deserialization: 

var dataList = (List<BusinessList>)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(reciveObject, typeof(List<BusinessList>), jsonSerializerSettings);
```

Error:

```
"Expected a JsonObjectContract or JsonDictionaryContract for 
type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1
[PathResultsPortal.UI.Controllers.AnalyteDetails]', 
got 'Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonArrayContract'."
```

If you remove the Codes List from the BusinessList Object it works fine it can't seem to handle the list with in a list, is it even possible?

Comment: Is there a reason Codes cant be a string[]

Comment: Ignore I'm an idiot. I was sending just a BusinessList object but trying to deserialise into a List. Works fine if you try to put it back together as the same object that was sent. *SLAP

Answer (score 0):

```
public class BusinessList 
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Number")]
    public long Number{ get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "BusinessUnitCode ")]
    public string BusinessUnitCode { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Codes ")]
    public List<Codes> Codes { get; set; }
}

public class Codes
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
}
```

try this